# Put record into DHT

Tags: rust, ipfs, libp2p

I'm trying to insert a simple `/pk` record to the IFPS DHT using Rust and [rust-libp2p](https://github.com/libp2p/rust-libp2p)

Here's my code (Rust 1.55, libp2p-rust 0.39.1):

```rust
let mut key = "/pk/".bytes().collect::<Vec<_>>();
key.append(&mut local_key.public().into_peer_id().to_bytes());
let key = Key::from(key);
let mut value = local_key.public().into_protobuf_encoding();

kademlia_swarm.behaviour_mut().put_record(Record{
    key,
    value,
    publisher: None,
    expires: None
}, Quorum::One).expect("call put_record");
```

This code successfully finds 20+ peers to insert the record to, but the insertions always fail. When I run my code with `RUST_LOG=debug`, I see that every peer terminates the connection with EOF during the insertion. Calling `kademlia::bootstrap()` doesn't help.

FYI, when I run something very similar using Go and [go-libp2p](https://github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p), it works as expected:

```golang
publicKeyBytes, _ := localKey.GetPublic().Bytes()
pid, _ := peer.IDFromPublicKey(localKey.GetPublic())
key := "/pk/" + string(pid)
err = kademlia.PutValue(ctx, key, publicKeyBytes)
```

**Edit:** a bounty is awarded for a simple demonstration of how to add a record to the IPFS DHT using Rust and rust-libp2p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfunny story - my example presented in the question is correct - but there is a bug in rust-libp2p which breaks the interoperability with go-libp2p. See https://github.com/libp2p/rust-libp2p/pull/2309 for details